# Echoing all comments in Table

Tags: php, comments

Before I say anything I'll just post my index.php to allow you guys to get an idea of what it looks like first:

```
<script>
function submitLikeForm()  {
var form = jQuery("#like_form");
    $.ajax({ type: "GET", url: form.attr("action"), data: form.serialize(), success:    function() });
}
</script>

<script>
function leaveYourComment()  {
var form = jQuery("#comment_form");
    $.ajax({ type: "GET", url: form.attr("action"), data: form.serialize(), success: function() });
}
</script>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">

</head>

<body>

<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("No SQLI");//run query to display all images uploaded by users

    mysqli_select_db($conn, "sample") or die ("No DB");

$sqli = "SELECT * FROM `photos` ORDER BY `id` DESC";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqli) or die ("No query");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))    {

$username = $_SESSION['id'];

$title = $row['title'];

$description = $row['description'];

$image_name = $row['image_name'];

$random_directory = $row['random_direc'];

$date = date('M/d/Y');

$image_info = "http://localhost/splindr_2.0/photos/$random_directory/$image_name";

$sqli = ("SELECT * FROM `likes` WHERE `hidden_name` = '$image_name' AND `hidden_folder` = '$random_directory'");//run query to get likes

$likes_result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqli) or die ("No query");

$liked_count = '0' ; $unliked_count = '0';

while($likes_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($likes_result))  { 

if($likes_row['liked_unliked'] == 0)  { 

      $unliked_count++; 

           } else { 

      $liked_count++; 

     }

}

$comment_count = ("SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE `hidden_folder` = '$random_directory' AND `hidden_name` = '$image_name'");//run query to get comments

$comment_query = mysqli_query($conn, $comment_count) or die ("No query");

$total_comments = mysqli_num_rows($comment_query);

while($comment_result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($comment_query)) {

  $comment = $comment_result['comment'];

  $commented_on_by = $comment_result['commenting_user'];

}

echo "<div id='contentWrapper'>

          <div class='photo'>

              <div class='actual_image'>

                 <img src='$image_info'>

              </div>          

              <div class='like_system'>

                                        <form name='like_form' id='like_form' action='liked_button.php'>

                                           <input type='image' img src='https://i.imgur.com/pMmYaYM.jpg' class='like_button button' name='like_button' onClick='return submitLikeForm()'>

                                           <input type='hidden' name='hidden_image' class='hidden_image' value='$image_info'>

                                           <input type='hidden' name='hidden_folder' class='hidden_folder' value='$random_directory'>

                                           <input type='hidden' name='hidden_name' class='hidden_name' value='$image_name'>

                                           <input disabled type='text' name='total_likes' class='total_likes' value='$liked_count'>

                                        </form>

                                           <a style='color: #2e4987;text-decoration:none' href='http://www.twitter.com/share?url=$image_info&hashtags=Splindr, CheckThisOut'>

                                           <img class='twitter_button button' name='twitter_button' src='http://i.imgur.com/hKFKJoj.jpg'></a>

                                           <img src='http://i.imgur.com/8azoFjh.jpg' class='show_comments button' name='show_comments'>

                                           <input disabled type='text' class='comment_count' name='comment_count' value='$total_comments'>

                                           <img class='delete_button button' name='delete_button' src='http://i.imgur.com/wKZu2H1.jpg'>

              </div> 

                    <div class='info_wrapper'>

                       <div class='info_header'>Title: $title &nbsp By: $username &nbsp Date: $date</div>

                           <div class='description'>$description</div>

                    </div>

                    <div class='comment_wrapper'>

                      <div class='close_comment'>[close comments]</div>

                       <div class='comment_box_wrapper'>

                        <div class='comment_box'>

                            <div class='commenter'>$commented_on_by</div>

                            <div class='profile_pic'><img src='https://i.imgur.com/1MkFvhU.png'></div>

                            <div class='actual_comment custom_scrollbar'>$comment</div>

                        </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class='post_comment'>

                          &nbsp &nbsp <a style='color:#9b6bb4 ; text-decoration:none ; position:relative ; top:-5px ; left:-5px'></a>

                          <form name='comment_form' id='comment_form' action='leave_comments.php' onSubmit='return validateForm()'>

                                      <input type='text' name='user_comment' class='user_comment' placeholder='Leave a comment...'>

                                      <input type='hidden' name='hidden_image' class='hidden_image' value='$image_info'>

                                      <input type='hidden' name='hidden_folder' class='hidden_folder' value='$random_directory'>

                                      <input type='hidden' name='hidden_name' class='hidden_name' value='$image_name'>

                                      <input type='image' img src='http://i.imgur.com/8azoFjh.jpg' class='leave_comment button' name='leave_comment button' onClick='return leaveYourComment ()'>

                          </form>

                        </div>

                    </div>

              </div>

          </div>";

        }

?>
```

Okay so basically, so this index.php page is where images go after users upload them. Users can comment and like posts/images.

The problem I'm having is with my comments system. The comments are uploaded to mysqli just fine, however, I'm having trouble echoing each individual comment out. Multiple comments are shown in my table, but when I post a new comment, the new comment just replaces the previously posted comment. I don't want this, I want every comment to display by `id DESC`.

I've tried a loop for the comments (as you can see in the code above), but like I said, it just makes the newest comment replace the older comment.

So how can I correct my code so that all comments show in a `comment_box` within the `comment_box_wrapper`, with the respective information of the user that posted the comment.

I've struggled with this all day so any help will be appreciated.

Let me know if you need me to post anything else. I only posted the index.php because everything else is working and the problem is located only on this page.

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning the $comment and $commented_by variables in a loop, effectively overwriting them, without using them.

You'd need to split you one big `echo`, and replace the comment_box part with something like this:

```
while($comment_result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($comment_query)) {
  echo "<div class='comment_box'>";
    echo "<div class='commenter'>".$comment_result['commenting_user']."</div>";
    echo "<div class='profile_pic'><img src='https://i.imgur.com/1MkFvhU.png'></div>";
    echo "<div class='actual_comment custom_scrollbar'>".$comment_result['comment']."</div>";
  echo "</div>";
}
```

As you see above, we print each comment data, on each iteration of the loop.